# Non repeating Random Numbers 2D Vector (C++)

Tags: c++, vector, random, numbers

*EDIT*: I am currently working on a project. I am almost finished, although I can not seem to figure out how to populate my vector(matrix) with non repeating random numbers. I am getting random numbers, but some of them are repeating. I tried implementing a method that checks to see if a number pushed to the vector already exists, but that does not work.

Is there an easy way to go about this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

/*
The purpose of this program is to create a matrix using 2D vectors, then decide
if it is a perfect matrix or not.
*/

void matrix(int );

int main()
{
    int input;
    char again = 'y';

    cout << "Welcome to my perfect matrix program. The function of the program is"
            "\nto:"
            "\n"
            "\n   1. Allow the user to enter the size of the perfect matrix, such as"
            "\n      N. N>=2."
            "\n   2. Create a 2 D vector array of size N x N."
            "\n   3. Populate the 2 D vector array with distinct random numbers."
            "\n   4. Display the sum for each row, column, and diagonals then"
            "\n      determine whether the numbers in N x N vector array are perfect"
            "\n      matrix numbers.";
    cout << endl << endl;

    while(again == 'y' || again == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "\nEnter the size of the matrix : ";
        cin >> input;

        while(input < 2)
        {
            cout << "\nError *** Incorrect input - You entered a number < 2"
                    "\nEnter a Positive integer Number >= 2: ";
            cin >> input;
        }

        matrix(input);

        cout << "\nWould you like to find another perfect matrix?"
                "\nEnter y || Y for yes or n || N for no: ";
        cin >> again;

        if(again == 'N' || again == 'n')
        {
            cout << "\nThis perfect matrix algorithm is implemented by B"
                    "\nFebruary 13th - 2017\n";
        }

        while(again != 'Y' && again != 'y' && again != 'N' && again != 'n')
        {
            cout << "\nError *** Invalid choice - Must enter y|Y or n|N" << endl;
            cout << "\nWould you like to find another perfect matrix?"
                    "\nEnter y || Y for yes or n || N for no: ";
            cin >> again;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void matrix(int value)
{
    int N = value;
    bool isPerf = true;
    int sum = 0,
        i,
        j;

    int diagSum1 = 0,
        diagSum2 = 0;

    vector<vector<int> >arr;

    srand(time(0));

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        vector<int> temp;
        bool check;
        int digit;
        for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            do
            {
                digit = rand()%8;
                check = true;
                for(int k = 0; k < j; k++)
                {
                    if(digit == temp.front())
                    {
                        check = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }while(!check);
            temp.push_back(digit);
        }
        arr.push_back(temp);
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "The perfect matrix that is created for size " << value << ":";
    cout << endl << endl;

    for(i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j];
            cout << "   ";
        }
        cout << endl << endl;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); j++)
        {
            sum += arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    int perf = sum/3;

    cout << "The perfect number is: " << perf << endl << endl;

    for(i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        int rowSum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); j++)
        {
            rowSum += arr[i][j];
        }
        cout << "Sum of numbers in Row # " << i + 1 << " = " << rowSum;
        if(rowSum != perf)
        {
            isPerf = false;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;


    for(i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        int colSum = 0;
        for(j = 0; j < arr[i].size(); j++)
        {
            colSum += arr[j][i];
        }

        cout << "Sum of numbers in Column # " << i + 1 << " = " << colSum;
        if(colSum != perf)
        {
            isPerf = false;
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;


for(i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
{
        diagSum1 += arr[i][i];
        diagSum2 += arr[i][arr.size() - i - 1];
}

cout << "Sum of numbers in first diagonal    =   " << setw(3) << diagSum1 << endl;
if(diagSum1 != perf)
    {
        isPerf = false;
    }
cout << "Sum of numbers in second diagonal   =   " <<  setw(3) << diagSum2 << endl;
if(diagSum2 != perf)
    {
        isPerf = false;
    }

cout << endl;

if(isPerf)
{
    cout << "The above is a perfect matrix" << endl;
}
else
    cout << "The above is not a perfect matrix" << endl;

cout << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

One option is to create a temporary set for you to populate with your random numbers. Check the size of the set whenever you insert an element, and when the size is equal to the number of distinct elements required, iterate over the set to retrieve the values and populate the matrix.

```
...
std::set<int> distinct;
while (distinct.size() < input) {
        int r_num = /* random number generation */
        distinct.insert(r_num);
}
std::set<int>::iterator it;
for (it = distinct.begin(); it != distinct.end(); it++) {
        /* method of adding to matrix */ = *it;
}
...
```